# Android webview ban zoom on multitouch

Tags: android, webview

How i can do that? Id like to ban the zooming of the webview in multitouch.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code
 `WebSettings settings = mWebview.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(false);`